# Check if any points of an objects bounding box is inside the bounding box of another object

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, matrix

I'm trying to make a script that'll find if any points of an objects bounding box is inside the area of a different objects bounding box.

My thought was to cancel out the rotation of the object I'm checking against so that I can just do a simple `point.x > minX and point.x < maxX` check to see if its inside. I would essentially move everything into the relative space of the object I'm checking against.

I've almost got a solution working, I'm using a matrix invert on the active object (the one I'm using as the area to check against) so everything is axis absolute and then I translate each other selected object into that relative space.

The problem is that I don't understand how to keep the relative rotation of the other objects intact as currently it removes all rotation for all objects:
[image]
[image]

Here's the code I'm using to get the positions of the corners (also spawning empties to make it easier to see)

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
act_obj = context.active_object
sel_obj = context.selected_objects


#this section is to make sure the scale of the active object is applied
originalSel = sel_obj

for obj in sel_obj:
    obj.select_set(False)

act_obj.select_set(True)

bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(
    location=False, rotation=False, scale=True, properties=False)


#debug create an empty to see where the points are
def createEmpty():
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new( "empty", None )

    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link( obj )

    obj.empty_display_size = 1
    obj.empty_display_type = 'PLAIN_AXES'

    return obj

#get the relative locations of the corners of the bounding box
def calculateBounds(matrix_world_inverted, obj):
    local_pos = matrix_world_inverted @ obj.matrix_world.translation.copy()

    allVertPositions = []
    

    for vert in obj.bound_box:
        empty = createEmpty()
        vertPos = []
        for i in range(3):
            vertPos.append(local_pos[i] + (vert[i] * obj.scale[i]))
            empty.location[i] = local_pos[i] + (vert[i] * obj.scale[i])
        allVertPositions.append(vertPos)

    return allVertPositions


#get the active objects inverted matrix (so we can work with absolute axis)
matrix_world_inverted = act_obj.matrix_world.copy().inverted()

#create empties for each corner of all selected objects
for obj in sel_obj:
    objVerts = calculateBounds(matrix_world_inverted, obj)
```

How would I go about making sure that the relative (to the bix box) location of the small box stays intact? Is there an easier way than what I'm doing?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but couldn't you transform all coordiantes into world space and compare them there? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8470
Or is it the goal to transform them into the space of the active object?

Comment: Since I want to check if any of the points (bounding box corners) of selected objects are inside the active objects bounding box I assume its easiest to move everything into an "absolute axis" so its an easy "point.x > minX and point.x < maxX" check after

Comment: Right, that makes sense and would also be useful for other users. 

Just in case you are not looking for the most elegant and efficient solution though, you could also work in global space and use a [BVHTree](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.bvhtree.html). https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173356/blender-crashes-when-running-trying-to-overlap/173527

Comment: Thanks for the links, Ill take a look!

Comment: Using BVHTree like in your answer in the other post turned out to be a much easier solution to my problem. Annoying that I didnt find that out before spending time trying to wrap my head around matrix multiplication haha.
Thanks again!